# Indices, Combining Sum and Product Notation

Tags: polynomials, notation, article-writing, index-notation

I have a function 
$$ f(x) = (x-a_1)(x-a_2) \cdot \cdot \cdot (x-a_n) $$

I want to express $f'$ with sigma notation. It is clear that $f'$ is the sum of $n$ terms, where each term is missing one $(x-a_i)$. So I want to sum over n terms, and for each term I want to multiply all but one $(x-a)$ in the original polynomial.

I think it is:
$$ f'(x) = \sum_{\substack{i = 1}}^n  \prod_{\substack{j \neq i}}^n  \;(x-a_j) $$
An alternative is
$$ f'(x) = \sum_{i = 1}^n \prod_{\substack{i = 1 \\j \neq i}}^n  \;(x-a_j) $$

> Does this say what I want it to say?

**Edit:**

The correct notation is 
$$ f'(x) = \sum_{\substack{i = 1}}^n  \prod_{\substack{j = 1 \\ j \neq i}}^n  \;(x-a_j) $$

Comment: Those aren't sigmas. Those are pis. Compare: $\Sigma$ vs. $\Pi$. That being said, the first is appropriate. Multiply over all $j \neq i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it says what you want it to say. For every $i,$ you're only multiplying the $(x-a_j)$'s that are not equal to $(x-a_i).$

Comment: Is one of the two options I have in my post better than the other?

Comment: The first one is correct and very intuitive, but the second is incorrect. You're not adding anything in the second one; just multiplying.

Comment: No problem, I'll accept your answer as soon as it lets me. A small question, in the first notation, should it be a product only over $i \neq j$, or should I give it an upper limit of $n$? (I have the upper limit in the post, I'm not sure it makes sense though).

Comment: Actually, I think it makes sense to have the product go from $j=1, j \neq i$ to $j=n$. ?

Answer (score 3):

An elegant alternative is to index over a set. For $j \in \{1,\dots,n\}$, let $I_j := \{1,\dots,n\} \backslash\{j\}$.

Now, if 
$$f(x) = \prod_{j=1}^n (x-a_j),$$
then 
$$f'(x) = \sum_{j=1}^n \prod_{k \in I_j}(x-a_k).$$